# Are HTML helpers worth using with complex markup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

**Should I persist with using HTML helpers, or just use plain HTML?**

I've been using HTML helpers for a while now and really enjoyed using them. Recently I've started using CSS frameworks such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and I'm finding that my markup is too complex to use the standard HTML helpers.

Of course, I still use `Url.Action()` for generating links and sometimes `@Html.TextBoxFor()` or similar for simple forms, but, for example, I'm finding some helpers like `Html.ActionLink()` or `Using Html.BeginForm()` just don't cut it.

My markup often contains complex nests. For example, in Bootstrap I might want to add an icon as part of a link:

```
<a href="#">
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    <span>Simple link</span>
</a>
```

This is very common with Bootstrap and I feel like HTML helpers would get in the way. I can make my own, but my markup is quite different all over.

Suppose I only use HTML helpers in small amounts; where needed. This raises another question:

**If I'm minimising HTML helper usage, should I just drop them altogether and primarily use regular HTML for consistency?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm minimising HTML helper usage, should I just drop them
>   altogether and primarily use regular HTML for consistency?

No, always use HTML helpers. In the example of complex anchors you could still use the `Url.Action` helper to set its `href` attribute and hardcode the other parts of it.

Comment: Agreed. `Url.Action` would always be good for ensuring proper links and without magic strings. But I'm more referring to pure HTML tag generation helpers, such as generating forms and form fields. Is it good practice to not use them, or should I try to incorporate these helpers where possible?

Comment: No, always use them. `Html.BeginForm` helper and `Html.TextBoxFor` and similar should always be used. They provide you with overloads allowing to have full control over the generated markup. What might be problematic is indeed the `Html.ActionLink` which doesn't allow you to have complex inner HTML which is required by Bootstrapper. But this is not the case with Html.TextBoxFor or with forms.

Comment: You should also look at "my markup is quite different all over" and determine if a) it really is all that different and b) if it really needs to be different. Making use of the helpers can help enforce consistency which will pay you back in the future with simplified maintenance.

Comment: `Html.TextBoxFor` has anything special which plain HTML `<input type = "text" />` can't do ?

Comment: @PKKG, yes lots of special things. For example if you assign a value to the view model property this value will automatically be displayed in the generated input field. Also if there are validation errors it will append the proper class to the input field. Also it will generate HTML5 `data-*` attributes on the input field which are used by the unobtrusive validation.

Comment: Can you please explain why? :)

Answer (score 5):

I agree that Html tag helper can do as much to *obscure* meaning as convey it. We all understand Html (designers and developers) so why not use it? Html helpers simply revert us to the days of Asp.Net controls which emitted Html for us. As an example, which of these two is clearer?

```
@Html.ActionLink("About this Website", "About")
```

or

```
<a href='/about'>About this website</a>
```

Granted the second answer may have more characters, but is far clearer.

Comment: Exactly. I feel the same way: html helpers IMHO add a bit of un-readability element to the source. Non-razor savvy peeps will be pulling their hair out when they go back and forth between Build and View source to see the actual markup. Just my two $$$

Answer (score 3):

When you have to start doing more advanced things with page elements it starts to get ugly. I always found myself having to go to the rendered page source to see exactly what was generated way to many times. Another issue is when you have a designer trying to style your markup, most will know html but not razor/aspx syntax.

My advice is to do straight html for any site that will utilize a good amount of js libs (jquery/knockout/angular/etc). Especially the form helpers.