# Should I use DisplayNameFor method in C# mvc or avoid it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

In a View auto generated, I could see a couple of lines like:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RestarauntName)
    </th>
</tr>
```

I thought of writing something like this:

```
<table>
@{
            <th>
                 @typeof(Tutorial.Models.RestarauntReview).GetProperty("RestarauntName").Name
             </th>
        }
```

and it worked too!

So my guess is that the DisplayNameFor() method uses reflection to find the name of the corresponding property.

Here's something I break my head off.

1. What is the cost of using reflection ?
2. For smaller views that we want to be rendered quicky can we just type the name of the property ? (hardcoding ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my guess is that the DisplayNameFor() method uses reflection

Not directly, I suspect. It's more likely that is uses [ModelMetaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata(v=vs.108).aspx) (which no doubt uses reflection eventually if you follow the trail).

> For smaller views that we want to be rendered quicky can we just type the name of the property ?

You can. It might be ok for a fairly small and unchanging project but I wouldn't necessarily recommend it.

> What is the cost of using reflection ?

I think you'll find it to be insignificant for most purposes. It's one of those cases in which it's not a concern unless it becomes a concern (duck, recursion!).

The greater concern is: **Is reflection the best way to achieve my goal?** I think that's the question you should be asking. Reflection is great fun (I know) but it's also a bit hard to read and can be hard to debug. That's why it's probably best to avoid it if there is an alternative. In this case there is: **ModelMetaData**.

What I mean by that is: **do try to use HTML Helpers**, and if they don't quite do what you want then try to extend them and create your own. Try to fall in love with [Display Templates and Editor Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) and use them in conjunction with ModelMetaData.

The problem with using reflection in the Razor View is that you're putting the wrong things in the view. [Views should be stupid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ku3QkWcPSEw) - meaning they shouldn't have any logic in them or really be 'doing much' of anything. You just pass the views data and they'll display it for you.

I asked the (slightly related) question [Are HTML helpers worth using with complex markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654985/are-html-helpers-worth-using-with-complex-markup) which you might find interesting.